# Any reason to save a file before converting to Base64 to pass on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an attachment section for a webpage that takes said attachment, converts it to base64 and passes it to xml gateway.

Is there any reason for me to save said file locally? The file size limit is 5mb.

Current set up seems to work;

```
byte[] attachBytes = new byte[attach.ContentLength];
using (BinaryReader theReader = new BinaryReader(attach.InputStream))
{
      attachBytes = theReader.ReadBytes(attach.ContentLength);
}

model.filename = attach.FileName;
model.base64convert = Convert.ToBase64String(attachBytes);
```

VS Saving(File isn't required to be stored on the server)

```
attach.SaveAs("C:/temp/Attachfiles/" + attach.FileName); 
byte[] attachBytes = new byte[attach.ContentLength];
using (BinaryReader theReader = new BinaryReader(attach.InputStream))
{
      attachBytes = theReader.ReadBytes(attach.ContentLength);
}

model.filename = attach.FileName;
model.base64convert = Convert.ToBase64String(attachBytes);
```

Mainly just wondering the downsides of doing it how I am. I'm thinking there is no difference as I am not reading the saved file back in but I'm still learning and don't want to miss anything.

Comment: It is an opinion so probably off-topic, but if you don't have this requirement then why do you want to store it? Are you planning some kind of resend functionality?

Comment: The main downside to not saving the file is that you will lose the file if the stream is disposed before you process it, this means that unless you save it you must process the file immediately and can't queue it to be processed later. as long as that isn't a requirement then their is no value in saving the file

Comment: You *are* saving the file, by passing it to the gateway. You do not need to save the file on the local filesystem, and indeed, it would be bizarre to do so for most web applications. Do not save it locally unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Perfect thanks everyone the main reason I wasn't doing it was because it wasn't a requirement mentioned but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit open ended, but answerable.

If you have to have some record of receiving the file before sending it on, then save it. However, there *are* downsides to saving a file

- you could run out of space
- the file, if it contains anything sensitive, is stored in the clear
- you're introducing a point of failure (e.g. can't save file) for no gain

So, as specified, don't do it. If your requirements evolve you can always re-evaluate that decision.

As mentioned in the comments, a save may be reasonable *if* you are doing something like a resend in case of failure; but even then I suggest not keeping the file around forever, and usually storage at/on a web server is a bad idea for the reasons above.

Comment: you can still create a record of the file with out saving

Comment: Perfect rundown for what I needed to hear thanks.